# How Lambda operator () -> works?

Tags: java, spring, akka

I would like to understand, how the below code works.

```
@Bean
public StateHandlerDef handler() {
    return () -> StateOne.class;
}

@Named
@Scope("prototype")
public class StateOne extends AbstractStateActorActor<StatObject> {

    @Inject
    public StateOne(final Props prop, final StatRegistry statRegistry) {
        super("test", transformationConfig, GenericStateObject.class, statRegistry);
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface StateHandlerDef {
    Class<? extends AbstractUntypedActor> getHandlerClass();
}
```

This is the working code.

I would like to understand, How the bean creation work here.

Below code creates a bean.

```
@Bean
public StateHandlerDef handler() {
    return () -> StateOne.class;
}
```

StateOne class has a constructor. But, this creates the bean without passing the constructor arguments. Also, the return type is a function interface which is not implemented by the actual state class and not sure how does it work. This is based an Akka actor model.

```
AbstractStateActorActor extends AbstractUntypedActor
```

Here, I would like to set the bean name programmatically instead of setting thru the annotation.

> @Bean("test")

If I try BeanPostProcessor for programmatically setting the bean name, it throws error that instance cannot be created using new and should be created with actorof.

```
Caused by: akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: You cannot create an instance of [com.test.Test] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the documentation.
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:181) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.19.jar:na]
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this think of it this way. The library that you are trying to extend (in this case akka) needs to know the class that is going to handle a state. To do that it gets an instance (bean) of type `StateHandlerDef`. This instance is created by the lambda expression in this code:

```
@Bean
public StateHandlerDef handler() {
    return () -> StateOne.class;
}
```

which is equivalent to something like:

```
@Bean
public StateHandlerDef handler() {
    return new StateHanderDefImpl();
}
```

The library will use this to get `StateOne.class`, for which it will look for a bean and will get it from the dependency injection framework. That bean is defined here:

```
@Named
@Scope("prototype")
public class StateOne extends AbstractStateActorActor<StatObject> {

    @Inject
    public StateOne(final Props prop, final StatRegistry statRegistry) {
        super("test", transformationConfig, GenericStateObject.class, statRegistry);
    }
}
```

The DI framework will create a bean from this class by injecting the dependencies it needs in its constructor.

Comment: How can i programmatically change the bean name without hardcoding like @Bean("")

Comment: which bean name do you need to change? `StateOne` or `StateHandlerDef`?

Comment: @Bean
public StateHandlerDef handler()

Comment: For that I suspect you need to understand the inner workings of akka and how it wires these beans. I'm sorry I'm not familiar with akka to offer you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Functional interface there `StateHandlerDef` is in a way to represent the getter function `getHandlerClass()` that is defined within its class definition with a lambda definition. With the below declaration;

```
@Bean
public StateHandlerDef handler() {
    return () -> StateOne.class; // a supplier, no input, returns value (getter)
}
```

We are essentially implementing the `StateHandlerDef` interface by defining `getHandlerClass()` method. That is why the return value of the lambda is same as the getter method, `StateOne` is of type `Class<? extends AbstractUntypedActor>`.

So in a way the bean we created was like the following;

```
public interface StateHandlerDef {
    Class<? extends AbstractUntypedActor> getHandlerClass();
}

public class StateHandlerDefImpl implements StateHandlerDef {

    // explicit way of writing lambda "() -> StateOne.class"
    Class<? extends AbstractUntypedActor> getHandlerClass() {
        return StateOne.class;
    }
}

@Bean
public StateHandlerDef handler() {
    return new StateHandlerDefImpl();  // then we use the getter thru this bean.
}
```

With `@FunctionalInterface` we can skip the implementation of the interface as given above, and simply utilize the interface itself with the passed lambda (which is a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)).

Now you can just do this;

```
@Autowire
private StateHandlerDef handler;

public .. someLogic() {
    ...
    handler.getHandlerClass();  // will trigger the lambda, returning `StateOne.class`
    ...
}
```

You can change the name of the bean by just changing the name of its creation method. `@Bean handler()` will generate the bean with name `handler`.

I tried to simplify, hope it was understandable, otherwise please check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces)

Comment: How about the constructor arguments?

Comment: @user1578872 what constructor arguments? The return type of getter is [`Class`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-class-class-java-set-1/), not `StateOne`, there is no need for a constructor for a `Class` type, you can just use `StateOne.class`. It is of type `Class<? extends AbstractUntypedActor>` already.

Comment: I need to pass the arguments public StateOne(final Props prop, final StatRegistry statRegistry)  to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 1):

@FunctionInterface is special type of interface which actually restrict user not to include more than one SAM (Single Abstraction Method). For the below example we are having one method, It will provide any class which extends Object class.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ClassHandleDef {
  Class<? extends Object> getHandlerClass();
}
```

Now we are creating anonymous class of the interface ClassHandleDef and providing the body of the gethandlerClass method.

```
new ClassHandleDef() {
        @Override
        public Class<? extends Object> getHandlerClass() {
            return String.class;
        }
    };
```

Now we are removing the extra code which is not required. According the lambda expression remove all extra code and provide argument if there exist and body definition of the method along with lambda operator.

```
() -> String.class;
```

- If there is single line method definition then there is no need to write return statement explicitly.
- If there is single argument then there is no need of brackets. for example

  a -> a*2;

I hope, you understand the lambda expression working flow. Thanks for taking time to read this post.